# Change IBOutlet button's type

Tags: swift, uitableview, subclass, iboutlet

I'm trying to achieve something I'm not sure if it's doable. I have a xib for `UITableViewCell` that has a UIButton in it with custom class assigned in storyboard i.e `MainButtonSuperClass`. In `UITableViewCell.swift` outlet is connected like following,

```
@IBOutlet weak var button: MainButtonSuperClass!
```

Many different controllers are configuring this `TableViewCell` but button's UI will be different for all those controllers as defined in subclass i.e.

```
    final class MainButtonSubClass: MainButtonSuperClass {
        override func configure(){//different style of button }
    }
```

How can I achieve this? so far I have tried following,

```
let button: MainButtonSuperClass =  MainButtonSubClass()
button.configure()
cell.button = button
```

But this doesn't pick the style

**EDIT:**

```
//tableview cell
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var button: MainButtonSuperClass!
}

//Controller A wants default style of superclass (MainButtonSuperClass)
func configureButton(buttonCell: TableViewCell) {        
    buttonCell.button.configure() //works
}

//Controller B wants different style of subclass (MainButtonSubClass)
func configureButton(buttonCell: TableViewCell) {        
    let button: MainButtonSuperClass =  MainButtonSubClass()
    button.configure()
    cell.button = button // doesn't work or adopts the style
}


//Custom button's classes
final class MainButtonSuperClass: UIButton {
     override func configure(){//styled button }
}

final class MainButtonSubClass: MainButtonSuperClass {
     override func configure(){//different style of button }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to change the look of the button depending on which controller is in use?

Comment: Yes, different controllers are configuring this `TableViewCell` but they all will have different style of buttons. let's say `TableViewController` `Foo` wants cell blue button `TableViewController` Bar wants cell with black button. my super class for `UIButton` is in blue and subclass in black, `IBOutlet` is superclass as example but how other controllers will change that to subclass

Comment: @jay I have updated my question with more code if that clears it. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution. I will not use IBOutlet but just a property of UIButton that I will change dynamically with factory method. With IBOutlet it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Ok understand, let's try this

class CustomClass: UIButton {

```
class Type1Class: UIButton {
    // Do all the setup here

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

class Type2Class: UIButton {
    // Do all the setup here

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

}

Then you can initialize it with the following:

```
@IBOutlet weak var button: CustomClass.Type1Class!
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I want to have concrete class type and don't want to change them via switch

Comment: currently reference in `TableViewCell` is `@IBOutlet weak var button: MainButtonSuperClass!` so default style will be whatever is defined in `MainButtonSuperClass` some controllers wants the style defined in subclass

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the answer at first but I'm doing something similar the problem is my button is IBOutlet when you initialize it like, `let button = CustomClass.Type2Class()` then `iboutlet_button = button` it doesn't adapt the changes

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but how will this work? you're setting the type of the button `CustomClass.Type1Class!` inside tableviewcell which is configured in controller A, which wants style of type1class and will work just fine but controller b is also configuring this cell and wants style of `CustomClass.Type2Class!`

Comment: Yes, I think so

Comment: Sorry, that was my question about about controller b wanting to use same cell with same button but different style(`CustomClass.Type2Class`) how will it work in this fashion as type is hardcoded in `UITableViewCell` and not being changed from caller

Comment: Also, I can't have `required init?(coder: NSCoder)` as it's not only going to be called with tableviewcell

Comment: if we see my code above you can see what I tried on calling side, what's the type of button's iboutlet, and what subclasses I have. The only problem I have been unable to switch to subclass type of style when another controller wanted that.

Comment: I have added more code to my question if that helps. Thanks